# Using CalcLength to mark points on a segments using tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){X}
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,-2){Y}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1.5){Z}

\tkzDrawPolygon(X,Y,Z)

\tkzDefPoint(0,-5){A}
\tkzDefPoint(10,-5){B}

\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)


\tkzCalcLength[cm](X,Y) \tkzGetLength{XY}
\tkzCalcLength[cm](X,Z) \tkzGetLength{XZ}
\tkzCalcLength[cm](Y,Z) \tkzGetLength{YZ}

\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,X,Y,Z)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,X,Y,Z)

\begin{scope}[dim style/.style={dashed,sloped,teal}]
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\XY,6pt,text=red}](X,Y)
     \tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\XZ,6pt,text=red}](X,Z)
     \tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\YZ,6pt,text=red}](Y,Z)                                 
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to use this to give the same result was if I was to include the following code were G=XY, H=XZ and I=YZ, not have to work out the distance and have to input the coordinated by myself.

```
\tkzDefPoint(3.54,-5){G}
\tkzDefPoint(6.04,-5){H}
\tkzDefPoint(9.24,-5){I}

\tkzLabelPoints(G,H,I)
\tkzDrawPoints(G,H,I)
```

Comment: The calculated lengths are not as you write in the text.

Comment: They are the cumulative lengths plotted from A.

Comment: Yes cumulative and also changed around - e.g. G in not XY, but YZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){X}
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,-2){Y}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1.5){Z}
\tkzDrawPolygon(X,Y,Z)
\tkzDefPoint(0,-5){A}
\tkzDefPoint(10,-5){B}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzCalcLength[cm](X,Y) \tkzGetLength{XY}
\tkzCalcLength[cm](X,Z) \tkzGetLength{XZ}
\tkzCalcLength[cm](Y,Z) \tkzGetLength{YZ}
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,X,Y,Z)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,X,Y,Z)
\begin{scope}[dim style/.style={dashed, sloped, teal}]
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\XY, 6pt, text=red}](X,Y)
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\XZ, 6pt, text=red}](X,Z)
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\YZ, 6pt, text=red}](Y,Z)                                 
\end{scope}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:\YZ){G}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[G](0:\XZ){H}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[H](0:\XY){I}
%\tkzDefPoint(3.54,-5){G}
%\tkzDefPoint(6.04,-5){H}
%\tkzDefPoint(9.24,-5){I}
\tkzLabelPoints(G,H,I)
\tkzDrawPoints(G,H,I)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A triangle, a line and some points]

*Edit:* Here the points lie on AB independent on angle

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){X}
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,-2){Y}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1.5){Z}
\tkzDrawPolygon(X,Y,Z)
\tkzDefPoint(0,-5){A}
\tkzDefPoint(10,-5){B}
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzCalcLength[cm](X,Y) \tkzGetLength{XY}
\tkzCalcLength[cm](X,Z) \tkzGetLength{XZ}
\tkzCalcLength[cm](Y,Z) \tkzGetLength{YZ}
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,X,Y,Z)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,X,Y,Z)
\begin{scope}[dim style/.style={dashed, sloped, teal}]
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\XY, 6pt, text=red}](X,Y)
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\XZ, 6pt, text=red}](X,Z)
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\YZ, 6pt, text=red}](Y,Z)                                 
\end{scope}
\tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=\YZ](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{G}
\tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=\XZ](G,B) \tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=\XY](H,B) \tkzGetPoint{I}
\tkzLabelPoints(G,H,I)
\tkzDrawPoints(G,H,I)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is probably a better way that does not rely on the fact that AB is horizontal.

Comment: thanks @hpekristiansen your method would work for any line wouldn't it as long as you know the angle from 0 the line is.

Comment: Yes, -but just found a better way -see edit.

Answer (score 2):

I)  Slight modification of hpekristiansen's solution, which is the correct method.

The `cm` option is useless with `\tkzCalcLength`, since cm is now the default unit.

I've deleted `\tkzDrawPolygon(X,Y,Z)` because the segments are drawn with the `dim` option. If you use `tkzDrawPolygon` then you can pass `draw=none` with `dim` to avoid tracing the segments.

I've changed the display and I don't know if I've followed the order of the points.

And I've rearranged the order of the macros (def,calc,draw, label)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% def
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){X}
\tkzDefPoint(2.5,-2){Y}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1.5){Z}
\tkzDefPoint(0,-5){A}
\tkzDefPoint(10,-5){B}
% calc
\tkzCalcLength(X,Y) \tkzGetLength{XY}
\tkzCalcLength(X,Z) \tkzGetLength{XZ}
\tkzCalcLength(Y,Z) \tkzGetLength{YZ}
\tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=\YZ](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{G}
\tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=\XZ](G,B) \tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDefPointWith[linear normed,K=\XY](H,B) \tkzGetPoint{I}
% draw
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,X,Y,Z,G,H,I)
\begin{scope}[dim style/.style={dashed, sloped, teal}]
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\XY, -6pt, text=red}](X,Y)
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\XZ,  6pt, text=red}](X,Z)
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\pgfmathprintnumber\YZ, -6pt, text=red}](Y,Z)                    \end{scope}
% lab
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,Y)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](X)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](Z)
\tkzLabelPoints(G,H,I)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

II) Version with `lualatex and tkz-elements`

It's interesting because it's perfectly suited to this kind of figure. Point definition is straightforward. Next, we define the XYZ triangle, whose definition leads to the creation of attributes. What's interesting here are the side lengths. So `T.XYZ.a` is the length of the side opposite the first vertex X, so `a` corresponds to `YZ`, `b` to `XZ` and so on.

The `report` method transfers a length from a point in a direction defined by a straight line. Thus `z.H = L.AB : report (T.XYZ.a,z.G)` defines a point H such that `GH= T.XYZ.a = YZ` and `GH || AB`. With `z.G = L.AB : report (T.XYZ.c)` the starting point is omitted, so point A is chosen, i.e. `AG= T.XYZ.c = XY` and `AG || AB`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}

\begin{document} 
    
\begin{tkzelements}
z.X = point : new ( 0  , 0 )
z.Y = point : new ( 2.5  , -2 )
z.Z = point : new ( 2  , 1.5 )
z.A = point : new ( 0  , -3 )
z.B = point : new ( 10  , -3 )
T.XYZ = triangle : new ( z.X , z.Y , z.Z )
L.AB = line : new ( z.A , z.B )
z.G = L.AB : report (T.XYZ.c)
z.H = L.AB : report (T.XYZ.a,z.G)
z.I = L.AB : report (T.XYZ.b,z.H)
\end{tkzelements}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzGetNodes
% draw
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,X,Y,Z,G,H,I)
\begin{scope}[dim style/.style={dashed, sloped, teal}]
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{T.XYZ.c}}, -6pt, text=red}](X,Y)
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{T.XYZ.b}},  6pt, text=red}](X,Z)
\tkzDrawSegment[dim={\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{T.XYZ.a}}, -6pt, text=red}](Y,Z)                  
\end{scope}
% lab
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,Y)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](X)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](Z)
\tkzLabelPoints(G,H,I)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

III) Version with a few additional ideas. a,b,c are attributes of the triangle but alpha,beta and gamma are also attributes of the triangle. I also show the other possibilities of the `report` method.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements,amsmath}

\begin{document} 
    
\begin{tkzelements}
z.X = point : new ( 0  , 0 )
z.Y = point : new ( 2.5  , -2 )
z.Z = point : new ( 2  , 1.5 )
z.A = point : new ( 0  , -3 )
z.B = point : new ( 10  , -3 )
T.XYZ = triangle : new ( z.X , z.Y , z.Z )
L.AB = line : new ( z.A , z.B )
z.G = L.AB : report (T.XYZ.c)
z.H = L.AB : report (T.XYZ.a,z.G)
z.I = L.AB : report (T.XYZ.b,z.H)
z.M = point : new ( 0 , -4 )
z.N = point : new ( 0 , -5 )
z.O = point : new ( 0 , -6 )
z.m = L.AB : report ( T.XYZ.c , z.M )
z.n = L.AB : report ( T.XYZ.a , z.N )
z.o = L.AB : report ( T.XYZ.b , z.O )
z.w = point : new ( 6 , 0 )
z.x = point : new ( 6+T.XYZ.b , 0)
t = z.w : rotation (T.XYZ.alpha,z.x)
a = z.w : rotation (T.XYZ.alpha,z.x).argument
z.y = z.w + point : polar (T.XYZ.c, T.XYZ.alpha)
z.z = z.w + point : polar (T.XYZ.a, T.XYZ.alpha+T.XYZ.beta)
z.t = z.w + point : polar (T.XYZ.b, T.XYZ.alpha+T.XYZ.beta+T.XYZ.gamma)
\end{tkzelements}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzGetNodes
% draw
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B w,x w,t)
\tkzDrawSegments[blue](M,m w,y) 
\tkzDrawSegments[red](N,n w,z) 
\tkzDrawSegments[green](O,o w,x w,t)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,X,Y,Z,G,H,I,M,N,O,m,n,o,w,x,y,z,t)
\begin{scope}[dim style/.style={dashed, sloped, teal}]
\tkzDrawSegment[blue,dim={\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{T.XYZ.c}}, -6pt, text=red}](X,Y)
\tkzDrawSegment[green,dim={\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{T.XYZ.b}},  6pt, text=red}](X,Z)
\tkzDrawSegment[red,dim={\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{T.XYZ.a}}, -6pt, text=red}](Y,Z)                  
\end{scope}
% lab
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,Y)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](X)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](Z)
\tkzLabelPoints(G,H,I)
\begin{scope}[st/.style ={above,font=\scriptsize}]
  \tkzLabelSegment[st](M,m){\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{T.XYZ.c}}}
  \tkzLabelSegment[st](N,n){\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{T.XYZ.a}}}
  \tkzLabelSegment[st](O,o){\tkzDN{\tkzUseLua{T.XYZ.b}}}
\end{scope}

\tkzLabelAngle[pos= 1.3](x,w,y){$\widehat{X}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos= 1.3](y,w,z){$\widehat{Y}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos= 1.3](z,w,t){$\widehat{Z}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]